# Java do while loop error in Eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to write a bot that can click some buttons in a software, I want it to click 1000 times. I am using a while do loop  for it to work.
I get an error saying "click cannot be resolved to a variable" with this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{
        do{
            int click;
            click = 1;
            Robot myRobot = new Robot();
            myRobot.mouseMove(10,660);
            myRobot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            myRobot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            myRobot.delay(12000);
            myRobot.mouseMove(1200,100);
            myRobot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            myRobot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            myRobot.delay(3000);
            myRobot.mouseMove(500,80);
            myRobot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            myRobot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            click += 1;
        } while(click != 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: declare `click` outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will never exit. You are reinitializig click to 1 in every iteration. Do

```
int click = 1;
do{
Robot myRobot = new Robot();
myRobot.mouseMove(10,660);
//your code
click += 1;
} while(click != 1000);
```

Reason you are getting the error is you have declared click inside the loop so it scope/visibility is inside the loop only. Program context cannot resolve it at the `while(click != 1000)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

your variable **click** seems that you try to access it out of its scope, try declare it the main() scope. Hope that helps - cheers.